# What happens to ipv6 request if Load-balancer is configured to receive IPV4 requests

Tags: networking, devops, ipv6, ipv4, amazon-elb

Hi everyone i am having a public load-balancer on aws that is configured to receive only IPV4 requests, what will happen to IPV6 requests will they het dropped can anyone give me a detailed explanation on this

Answer (score 0):

Any IPv4-only device ignores/drops IPv6 packets. IPv4 and IPv6 are different network-layer protocols that don't interact in general.